# How to express a tag question ("..., huh/right/don’t we?") in colloquial French?

Tags: expressions, questions, incises

I’ve already read over a similar question, and I still wonder if the following three phrases have nuances of meaning?

[Can we form question tags in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9155/can-we-form-question-tags-in-french)

> "Yeah, what a marvellous age we live in, **don’t we/huh/right**? Wonder what they will invent **next**!"
>
> 1. « Ouais, dans quelle époque on vit, **pas vrai** ?
> 2. « Ouais, dans quelle époque on vit, **c'est ça** ?
> 3. « Ouais, dans quelle époque on vit, **n'est-ce-pas** ?
>
> Qu'est-ce qu'ils vont **encore** inventer... »

Incidentally, can you use the word "*encore*" to mean "next" rather than "still" or "again"? In this particular context, what is the purpose of the phrase "*encore inventer*"?

Comment: The most common such is "*, non ?*"

Comment: or, "si ?" with a negative question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*C'est ça ?*" is used when there is a doubt, it is odd here as the question is rhetorical.

"*N'est-ce pas ?*" is too formal and clashes with the colloquial "*Ouais*".

*Encore* can indeed mean next.

I would then translate the English sentence that way:

> Ouais, dans quelle époque on vit, pas vrai ? Qu'est ce qu'ils vont pas encore inventer !

I added "*pas*" to make the sentence more idiomatic.

Comment: @jilliagre Thanks. The "pas" placed before "encore" has me puzzled. What purpose does the "pas" serve here?

Comment: "Qu'est-ce qu'ils vont encore inventer ?" would mean you are really wondering what they will invent next which is close to the English sentence. "Qu'est-ce qu'ils vont pas encore inventer ?" is more idiomatic and means you don't really care about what they will invent next, but simply state in a rhetorical way they keep inventing odd / unwanted things, .

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 2 is incorrect... I mean, we don't say that.
Sentence 1 is definitely what you should say in French. In fact, "pas vrai" is a colloquial form of "n'est-ce pas".
Which means that the third sentence is correct, but I may say unusual.