# Why is the following sentence expressed in the negative "ne ... pas" instead of the affirmative?

Tags: négation, questions

> « Pauvre Rylas... Combien de fois **ne** me suis-je **pas** disputé avec ce vieil homme... Je n'arrive pas à croire qu'il est mort... »
>
> "Poor Rylas... How many times I argued with that old man... I cannot believe he is gone..."

I wonder why the negative "**ne ... pas**" is used here when the original English sentence does ***not*** include the word "**not**". How does this "**ne ... pas**" version compare with the following?

> « Combien de fois me suis-je disputé avec ce vieil homme... »

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The negation is here to make clear this is a rhetorical question.

- With *Combien de fois **me suis-je disputé** avec ce vieil homme...*, you are asking for the count which isn't really the point
- With *Combien de fois **ne me suis-je pas disputé** avec ce vieil homme...*, you are just stating you argued a large number of times without actually asking anything.

This is exactly the reason why I added ***pas*** in my reply to another question of yours [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17776/1109).

Comment: Thanks. I find it interesting how you compose rhetorical questions in French. Could you come up with some other sentence that uses negation like this for the rhetorical purposes?

Comment: @pourraitpuet-etre When asking to your kid to go to bed : « Tu ne crois pas qu'il est l'heure d'aller te coucher ??? »