# What’s the French equivalent to ‘why not?’

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

I’m doing my french homework and I’m curious if the french/francophone people say ‘why not’ as ‘pourquoi non’. If not, what’s the equivalent of it?

Comment: Greg's answered it. I just wanted to add that *pourquoi non* would be (somewhat unsurprisingly) the translation to "Why 'no'?".

Comment: Also, in the special case: "*Do you want to come? -No. -**Why not**?*", in French we'll just use "*Pourquoi ?*", not "*Pourquoi pas ?*".

Answer (score 14):

There is a very common equivalent: *pourquoi pas ?*

Answer (score 3):

For queries like this one may consult the webpage linguee.fr.
In your case

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/why+not.html

shows how to interpret **why not** depending on the context. As the others have already pointed out it would mostly be **pourquoi (ne) pas**.

As a further example consider the case one wishes to find the interpretation of tag questions in French (..., isn't it?), that is the kind of question which seeks confirmation of a statement just made.

Le voilà (typing isn't it? in the search area):

https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=isn%27+t+it%3F

**EDIT**

One sees the common (mostly formal nonetheless; see the comments accompanied my response and the reference therein and the links below) **n'est-ce pas ?**

https://www.quora.com/What-does-Nest-ce-pas-mean-in-French-and-is-it-commonly-used-If-so-how

https://www.lawlessfrench.com/expresions/nest-ce-pas/

Comment: Beware of *n'est-ce pas*. It is almost never used in day to day French and I mostly read/hear it from non native people assuming it matches the usage of *isn't it* and similar question tags. See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9155/can-we-form-question-tags-in-french

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks a lot!!! I guess my french grammar books (for Greek or Anglophones) need an update:-)!

Comment: I concur with Jiliagre: a more common equivalent in every day conversations would be the shorter "non?" (only with a positive form), or "hein ?": *C'est chouette, non ?/C'est chouette, hein ?*

Comment: Upvoted just because the approach to answering is good. SE isn't a phrase lookup site but a place for holistic answers like "Here's how to solve this on your own / some relevant context."

Comment: @Greg : D'accord:-)! I modified slightly my answer to take into account the feedback.

Comment: @jlliagre : Strangely http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/n'est-ce%20pas does not mention the formal character of this structure (as far as I understood:-)!).

Comment: The issue is that n'est-ce pas is not "why not". It's: isn't it or doesn't it or hasn't it or won't it. etc. In English, we use the auxiliary for n'est-ce pas. Mais il parlait français, n'est-ce pas? But he spoke French, didn't he?

Comment: @Dimitris *N'est-ce pas* has disappeared because it is designed to be used in a dialogue (written or oral), but the register used in dialogues has obsoleted subject-verb inversion. The very large majority of people who still use *n'est-ce pas* nowadays are non native speakers.

Comment: https://www.lemonde.fr/blog/correcteurs/2006/11/30/ca-vous-cloue-lbec-nest-ce-pas/ Ça vous cloue le bec, n'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 2):

"Pourquoi pas ?" is indeed very common as a question for "why not?"
If you want to build a sentence out of it, you can say *Pourquoi ne pas ____ ?*, which stands for *why not ____?*

> Why not go to Paris instead?
>
> *Pourquoi ne pas aller à Paris à la place ?*

Comment: Why not **go** to Paris instead.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR as Greg wrote, say *pourquoi pas*.

In general, it's hard to predict whether *non* or *pas* will appear in a given expression. A good tool to resolve these cases is [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams).

For example, here's [a comparison of *pourquoi non* and *pourquoi pas*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pourquoi%20non%2Cpourquoi%20pas&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpourquoi%20non%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPourquoi%20non%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourquoi%20non%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpourquoi%20pas%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpourquoi%20pas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPourquoi%20pas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPourquoi%20Pas%3B%2Cc0) showing that *pas* wins:

[image: pourquoi pas vs. pourquoi non]

But here's [a comparison of *non seulement* and *pas seulement*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=non%20seulement%2Cpas%20seulement&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cnon%20seulement%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnon%20seulement%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNon%20seulement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20seulement%3B%2Cc0) showing that *non* wins:

[image: pas seulement vs. non seulement]

So it depends on the phrase.

To do a deeper check if you're still not sure which one to say after that, I suggest [linguee.fr](https://linguee.fr) as dimitris mentioned. There you can find translated chunks in English and French and make sure that it's used the way you think it is. Here's an example from [a search for *pourquoi pas*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=pourquoi%20pas) :

> Et **pourquoi pas** un vélo ou des chaussures de marche ?
>   → 
> **Why not** a bike or walking shoes?

As Arkeen wrote, when asking why not *do a specific thing*, you should use the regular negation *ne ... pas* followed by the infinitive :

> Pourquoi ne pas poser ta question en ligne ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that while, as already answered, ***pourquoi pas ?*** is the natural translation of "**why not?**", ***pourquoi non ?*** used to be valid and was still be used in the 20<sup>th</sup> century literary French.

Moreover ***pourquoi non ?*** can still be used in modern French but only in reply of a ***non*** and would match "**why no?**" instead of "**why not?**".

> *–  Tu viens ?
>
> –  Non !
>
> –  Pourquoi non ?*

Here, ***non*** is just repeated like any other word would be, e.g.:

> *–  Tu choisis quelle couleur ?
>
> –  Rouge.
>
> –  Pourquoi rouge ?* (Why red ?)